# Connection issue with MariaDB and HAProxy (cluster)

Tags: mariadb, haproxy, galera

I have a problem with the connection of my vm where haproxy is running, and the clusters. Let me explain the issue.
I’ve setup 2 galera cluster machine with MariaDB (IPs 192.168.0.1 and 192.168.0.2) and a haproxy host (IP 192.168.0.3). I’ve followed almost all tutorial I’ve found in internet but I have always the same problem: **I can’t connect and perform any query from the haproxy**

Actual state:

- galera work fine

  ```
  root@db1:# mysql -u root -pPASSWORD -e 'SELECT VARIABLE_VALUE as "cluster size" FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.GLOBAL_STATUS WHERE VARIABLE_NAME="wsrep_cluster_size"'
  +--------------+
  | cluster size |
  +--------------+
  | 2            |
  +--------------+
  ```
- haproxy is well installed, and a user with all privileges is present in the database. The config file for haproxy is the following:

  ```
  global
     log 127.0.0.1   local0                                                                  
     log 127.0.0.1   local1 notice                                                           
     maxconn 1024                                                                            
     user haproxy                                                                            
     group haproxy                                                                           
     daemon                                                                                  

     stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats.sock mode 600 level admin                           
     stats timeout 2m                                                                        

  defaults                                                                                        
     log     global                                                                          
     mode    http                                                                            
     option  tcplog                                                                          
     option  dontlognull                                                                     
     retries 3                                                                               
     option redispatch                                                                       
     maxconn 1024                                                                            
     timeout connect 5000ms                                                                  
     timeout client  50000ms                                                                 
     timeout server  50000ms                                                                 

  listen haproxy-monitoring                                                                       
     bind *:80                                                                               
     mode http                                                                               
     stats enable                                                                            
     stats show-legends                                                                      
     stats refresh   5s                                                                      
     stats uri       /                                                                       
     stats realm     Statistics                                                              
     stats auth      User:Password                                                         
     stats admin     if TRUE                                                                 

  frontend lb1db                                                                                  
     bind *:3306                                                                             
     default_backend         galera-cluster                                                  

  backend galera-cluster                                                                          
     balance roundrobin                                                                      
     server db1      192.168.0.1:3306 check weight 1                                        
     server db2      192.168.0.2:3306 check weight 1
  ```
- the screen of stats show the vm up and running 
  [image: HAProxy Statistics monitor]
- The my.cnf is the following:

  ```
  [galera]                                                                                        
  wsrep_on=ON                                                                                     
  wsrep_provider=/usr/lib/galera/libgalera_smm.so                                                 
  wsrep_cluster_address=gcomm://192.168.0.94,192.168.0.93                                         
  wsrep_node_addres=192.168.0.1. #vm1 IP; in the other config is present the vm2 IP                                                                  
  wsrep_node_name=db1                                                                             
  binlog_format=row                                                                               
  default_storage_engine=InnoDB                                                                   
  innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2                                                                      

  wsrep_cluster_name="Cluster_name"                                                                    
  wsrep_sst_method=rsync                                                                          
  bind-address=192.168.0.1  #vm1 IP; in the other config is present the vm2 IP
  ```

When I try to execute a query in the haproxy I have the following result:

```
mysql -u root -pPASSWORD --host=192.168.0.3 --port=3306
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.0.3' (111 "Connection refused")
```

As I wrote I followed several tutorial and the problem is always the same. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Is there anything from HAProxy in the syslogs?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot the current log file is empty, in the other 3 files (zipped) there are only this line: haproxy-systemd-wrapper[4414]: haproxy-systemd-wrapper: exit, haproxy RC=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command you are using is trying to connect to the database service on the HAProxy server. As far as I can tell from your description, there is no database service running on this server(192.168.0.3).

If you would want to connect to the database service, you would need to use the IP address or hostname of one of the servers in the Galera cluster - e.g. 192.168.0.1 or 192.168.0.2.

You would have to create a user in the database service to authorize this kind of access (It does not seem like you did that, from reading your post). Secondly, it is not really recommended to have any remote access as 'root' enabled.
You could create a remote user in the database cluster and grant some permissions. Login to one of the servers in the cluster and login to the database as root:

```
# mysql -u root -p
```

Then create the user with remote access and grant some privileges;

```
MariaDB [(none)]> create user 'haproxy'@'192.168.0.3'identified by 'aPassword';
MariaDB [(none)]> GRANT USAGE,REPLICATION CLIENT,PROCESS,SHOW DATABASES,SHOW VIEW ON *.* TO 'haproxy'@'192.168.0.3';
MariaDB [(none)]> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

And then try using the account 'haproxy' from the HAProxy server:

```
# mysql -u haproxy --host 192.168.0.1 -p
```

And this should now work. One thing I also noticed is that in your my.cnf for the cluster, your line with the cluster servers contains addresses other than those of the actual servers:

> wsrep_cluster_address=gcomm://192.168.0.**94**,192.168.0.**93**

If this is actually not an artifact of copying and pasting, please make sure these are consistent with your configuration.

Good luck!